# Am I moving from OO to Haskell in the correct manner?

Tags: haskell

In OO, I have objects (instances of classes). I create objects, they stick around in memory, and I act on them to modify them over time.

The way I see Haskell: I don't have objects. Nothing sticks around in memory really. Things are just momentarily created and passed around functions to create new momentary things. And so on. My first question: **Is this an accurate depiction of Haskell**?

Moving to Haskell, I sometimes don't really know where to begin. How do I solve the same problem I was solving in OO? So I just turn to what seems obvious: I create state data structures (usually using record syntax). These are sort of like objects so they're familiar to me (except they're momentary as I talked about above). Then I just create a bunch of functions that take in a state data structure ("object") plus some other data and return a new state data structure ("object") plus some other new data. That's all I'm finding myself doing. I can't imagine any other way of doing things. (Well, except where I create small pure utility functions. These sort of correspond to private methods in OO. Small utility functions for specific tasks.) Second question: **Does what I'm doing sound correct or am I on the wrong path?**

Comment: Values in Haskell "stick around" in the same way they do in OO language. Objects are usually created and destroyed all the time as the program is executed just like values in Haskell are collected after they are no longer required.

Comment: What about narrowing the discussion to something concrete. Give us an algorithm / computation, and we can compare and contrast OO vs Haskell implementations. Note that you can use mutable data structures in Haskell, but you also have the choice not to.

Comment: "create a bunch of functions that take in a state data structure ("object") plus some other data and return a new state data structure" - yep, that's the essence of FP. But we can use higher-order functions to define nice abstractions to fit many different patterns we find in our code (including those that are best thought of as "stateful"), and the type system makes these abstractions sensible and composable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather put it the other way around: in Haskell, nothing is momentary, or concerned with any kind of time scale at all. You define stuff *once and for all*, values “have always been and will always stay around”.

(Not really, of course; that would be terribly memory-inefficient. Stuff you haven't evaluated yet won't actually exist in memory, but only in an abstract thunk form, and stuff that isn't needed anymore will be garbage-collected just like in Java.)

Instead of thinking about how objects change in time, you just think about the end result, the “desired final state” right away.

Now, obviously often the whole purpose of a program is to *do stuff* in time, not just give some final result. Well, in Haskell we like to think of such processes in more of a big picture: you try to consider the entire behaviour, or “history of states”, as a single abstract super-value. For instance, Functional Reactive Programming describes the history of states as a *function of a time variable*. The function *has* many values over time, but the function itself *is* just a single value, that you define once and for all times.